# How to save columns seleted with iloc and find its mean

Tags: python, pandas

this is my first post. I am currently working on a project where I need to find the mean for certain sections of data for each state. This is one example for the state data. I am using Google Colab, Python and the Pandas API to do this.

I selected the column and rows needed using iloc command like this:

`AKInitialInvest = df.iloc[0:19, 7:8]`

and I tried to use the mean command:

`AK_Ini_Inv =  AKInitialInvest.mean(axis=1, skipna=False)`

but it did not work when I printed it so I tried to write it to the csv file like this:

`AK_Ini_Inv = AKInitialInvest.to_csv('SSBCI Transactions Dataset.csv', index = True )`

but when I printed the value stored, it just printed NaN for all of the rows.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Also does anyone have any idea on how to store these values in a new column and add it to the csv file? Thank you and happy holidays!

Comment: Note that your `AKInitialInvest` is a pd.Series, so it is 1D and does not have a second axis (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my first post as well on StackOverflow, but after years of learning from this great community I guess it's time to try to give back a bit (if I can).

If you write something like this:

```
AK_Ini_Inv =  AKInitialInvest.mean(axis=1, skipna=False)
```

it will apply the mean() function column-wise, returning a dataframe with one column (the column-wise mean) and the same number of rows of the original dataframe (assuming ***AKInitialInvest*** is a pandas dataframe).

```
 AK_Ini_Inv =  AKInitialInvest.mean(axis=0, skipna=False)
```

This one will do the same, but row-wise.

If you're trying to get the mean of the entire data section (i.e. a single number) you can combine the two above thus applying the mean() function twice:

```
AK_Ini_Inv = AKInitialInvest.mean().mean()
```

I'm no python expert, so maybe there's a quicker/more efficient way to do this though.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it turns out I was using the correct command but I had to add a space between the axis = and 1. Thank you again, happy holidays!